# Selecionar input com id != valor

Tags: jquery, seletores

um seletor assim:

```
$('#minhaDiv input[id!="meuId1"]');
```

é bem comun. Eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer algo do tipo:

```
$('#minhaDiv input[id!="meuId1" && id!="meuId8"]');
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu conheço dois meios de fazer isso:

```
$('#minhaDiv input[id!="meuId1"][id!="meuId8"]');
```

ou

```
$('#minhaDiv input').filter(function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var idInvalidos = [
        'meuId1',
        'meuId8',
    ];
    return !jQuery.inArray(id,idInvalidos);
});
```

Comment: uma outra possibilidade é `#minhaDiv input:not(#meuId1):not(#meuId8)`